# Auto adjust height of primeng splitter

Tags: css, angular, primeng

[codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/raohammad/angular-primeng-sandbox/main?workspaceId=0972a050-94aa-4174-aca4-653536f88f00&file=README.md)

I have a UI built with angular and primeng, embedding monaco-editor and other primeng components. I am unable to adjust auto-height of child components of the editor. Expected behavior is;

- when width and height of the right split panel is changed, embedded monacoeditor should change its width and height to fill 100%
- when tab on left-bottom panel is changed to Chart; chart component should fill 100% without changing the height of overall page (currently it expands vertical and page shows vertical scroll)

would really appreciate a help.